# Drop rows based on float length in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, subset

I have a DataFrame with zip codes, among other things. The data, as a sample, looks like this:

```
     Zip    Item1     Item2   Item3
 78264.0      pan  elephant    blue
 73909.0  steamer     panda  yellow
  2602.0      pot     rhino  orange
 59661.0     fork     zebra   green
861893.0     sink    ocelot     red
 77892.0  spatula    doggie   brown
```

Some of these zip codes are invalid, having either too many or too few digits. I'm trying to remove those rows that have an invalid number of characters/digits (seven characters in this case, because I am checking length based on `str()` and the `.0` is included in there). The following `lengths` loop:

```
zips = mydata.iloc[:,0].astype(str)
lengths = []
for i in zips:
    lengths.append(len(i))
```

produces a series (not to be confused with Series, although maybe it is--I'm new at Python) of zip code character lengths for each row. I am then trying to subset the DataFrame based on the information from the `lengths` variable. I tried a couple of different ways; this following was the latest version:

```
for i in lengths.index(i):
    if mydata.iloc[i:,0] != 7:
        mydata.iloc[i:,0].drop()
```

Naturally, this fails, with a `ValueError: '44114.0' is not in list` error. Can anyone give some advice as to how to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: if the zip codes are stored as floats, containing too few digits might be because they start with 0 (which is valid for zip codes), but those leading 0s get dropped for floats

Comment: can you post a snippet of your data for example

Comment: Correct. It's part of what I factored into my analysis. It's how I received the data, and it's part of why I now need to fix that. The data is damaged, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write this more concisely using Pandas filtering rather than loops and ifs.

Here is an example:

```
valid_zips = mydata[mydata.astype(str).str.len() == 7]
```

or

```
zip_code_upper_bound = 100000
valid_zips = mydata[mydata < zip_code_upper_bound]
```

assuming fractional numbers are not included in your set. Note that the first example will remove shorter zips, while the second will leave them in, which you might want as they could have had leading zeros.

Sample output:

With `df` defined as (from your example):

```
        Zip    Item1     Item2   Item3
0   78264.0      pan  elephant    blue
1   73909.0  steamer     panda  yellow
2    2602.0      pot     rhino  orange
3   59661.0     fork     zebra   green
4  861893.0     sink    ocelot     red
5   77892.0  spatula    doggie   brown
```

Using the following code:

```
df[df.Zip.astype(str).str.len() == 7]
```

The result is:

```
       Zip    Item1     Item2   Item3
0  78264.0      pan  elephant    blue
1  73909.0  steamer     panda  yellow
3  59661.0     fork     zebra   green
5  77892.0  spatula    doggie   brown
```

Comment: I do these index functions in R all the time, but I'm not familiar enough with Python's index functions yet. I'm going to be referencing this question many times in the future. Where can I find the documentation for Python bracket indexing and slicing?

Comment: The slice notation is shorthand for using [.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) which accepts a boolean series of the same shape and returns rows for which the series is `True`, you can think of it as getting rows for which the condition (in brackets) is true. Here is a long page on indexing and selecting in Pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.len`

```
df[df.iloc[:,0].astype(str).str.len()!=7]
          A
1  1.222222
2  1.222200
```

dput :

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1.22222,1.222222,1.2222]})
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

`df1 = df['ZipCode'].astype(str).map(len)==5`